# Running a Jython app on WebSphere Liberty

Tags: java, websphere, jython, mod-wsgi, websphere-liberty

I'm looking to run a jython/modjy (modjy is kinda analogous to mod_wsgi except it bridges java web servers and applications) on my IBM WAS 8.5 Liberty Profile.

However when I convert the jython-modjy sample app into a .WAR file and put it in the dropins directory, the WebSphere server really struggles to find the path of the demo_app.py (WSGI handler). Here's a snippet of my web.xml file:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>python.home</param-name>
  <param-value>C:/jython2.5.3</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>app_filename</param-name>
  <param-value>demo_app.py</param-value>
</init-param>
```

The only other app related parameters are app_directory and app_callable_name which default to the current directory and handler respectfully:

I get the following error when I try to run the app:

```
modjy.modjy_exceptions.ApplicationNotFound: Application filename not found: None/demo_app.py
```

The only way I've gotten it to work is by specifying an absolute path, which really isn't too portable

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks, David

Comment: I don't know, but my recommendation would be to debug/trace the modjy code to determine what is causing the difference in behavior.  It's likely that a Liberty API (javax.servlet or ClassLoader would be my guess) is returning a different value from Tomcat (e.g., getRealPath because the .war is not expanded on disk?).

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test myself and I share the same apprehension raised by bkail. This issue is most likely the result of Liberty's behavior of not inflating deployed web applications. Therefore, all applications which rely on `getRealPath()` will fail.

There are two possible options/workarounds:

1. In a development environment, you can use Eclipse with the WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile Tools to add your Dynamic Web Module project to your Liberty server instance. This will create a link between Liberty and your project files in your workspace. The Servlet Context's `getRealPath()` method will work in this setup.
2. Inflate your WAR file in your Liberty server's `dropins` directory into a directory, which is called like the WAR file - including the file extension `.war`. The same approach should work with specifying your application in the `server.xml`.